# UWP/C# Background Downloader when minimize or background

Tags: c#, uwp, background

I have a UWP Application on store that downloads a playlist then convert them. I use `DownloadOperation` & `MediaEncodingProfile`

In store application version doesnt download a file when minimize or background and ocurres `OperationCancelled` & `BackgroundTransferStatus.Error` exceptions.

In Visual Studio Debugging version doesnt get any exceptions.

How i to do download in minimize or background ? How i to test in Debugging version ?

Comment: Please check background apps setting option if you have allowed your app running in background.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew i checked it is enable

Comment: I have tested with official code sample it works well in minimize  or background, you could provide a simple sample that could reproce this issue.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew Can you test with Relase Packages and use UWP.CORE 6.1.5?

Comment: Yep，I will try.